# Amazon RDS Rails postgis extension exists but type "geometry" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-rds, postgis

I am having a hard time using postgis on a RDS server.

Extension "postgis" exists and data are recorded correctly.

```rb
record.update(lonlat: 'POINT(2.4214133 48.7364525)')
=> true
```

```rb
record.lonlat
=> #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x30fe8 "POINT (2.4214133 48.7364525)">
```

But when I want to run a spatial query,

```rb
Records.where("ST_DWithin(records.lonlat, 'POINT(-1.548977 47.216369)'::GEOMETRY, '10000'::INTEGER)")
```

I get the following:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist)
```

I tried to drop the extension and create it again but I do not want to drop the data so it seems I cannot:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop extension postgis because other objects depend on it)
```

postgis is dedicated to a different schema that is included in the search path and I did grant all privileges on this schema.

On local and on heroku it works without any issue.

We use the gem `activerecord-postgis-adapter` https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter.

Here is my database.yml url line:

```yaml
url: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL', '').sub(/^postgres(ql)?/, "postgis") %>
```

Check on the postgis version:

```
postgres=> SELECT PostGIS_Version();
            postgis_version            
---------------------------------------
 3.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Sounds like the backup process is at fault. Anecdotally it is definitely possible to restore an RDS automated backup without causing any problems to PostGIS, I've done this several times. Are you using RDS backup or generating your own somehow?

Comment: @omnikron I am generating my own, provided by heroku, because my production app is still on heroku, the purpose of this staging is to test the migration from heroku to RDS. Before postgis it worked like a charm so I imagine as you say that the backup process is at fault somehow.

Comment: It's still weird, because any postgres instance I have ever had "on heroku" was anyway hosted on RDS! But sounds like that would be the culprit for sure. Maybe it is only backing up the public schema, and postGIS stores its types somewhere else? You'd need to track down the `geometry` type it is complaining about in a working database to be sure. Good luck!

Comment: @omnikron, thank you :) Indeed it is Amazon behind the scene, heroku forces every database to use a "heroku_ext" schema for every table using postGIS, I can say it is backed up as well, I need to create this secondary schema in order to use the backup on my local env, works like a charm. Same procedure on RDS.

Answer (score 1):

How are you connecting to your database, can you share your `config/database.yml` ? It may be that some postgis features are not supported by ActiveRecord out of the box.

We use [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) and have to specify that the adapter for the database is `postgis` not `postgres`, as recommended in the [gem docs](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter#databaseyml) (we actually do this by substituting `postgis` for `postgres` in the database `url`, so that it looks like `postgis://user:password@rds.instance.amazonaws.com/dbname` but the principle is the same:

```yaml
# config/database.yml
production: &default
  url: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL', '').sub(/^postgres/, "postgis") %>
```

Comment: Hi @omnikron thank you for your answer, I should have added this information, we use the same gem and replace the url too in the config.